# jQuery Drag and Drop binding multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I would like to have a list of Items that are bound to an Array.
For example
An Item would have a Title, Description, and an Image.

I would Have A Drop PlaceHolder that would have one or more of the "Title, Description, Image".

When I Drag the Item onto the PlaceHolder The components would be updated if they exist.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element being dragged with `ui.draggable`:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert:true });
$( "#placeholder" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var draggable = $(ui.draggable);
        var droppable = $(this);

        // Update droppable using draggable's sub-itens
        droppable.find(".title").html(draggable.find(".title").html());
        droppable.find(".description").html(draggable.find(".description").html());
        droppable.find(".image").attr("src",draggable.find(".image").attr("src"));
    }
});
```

The rest will depend on what you want to do with the draggable: copy their sub-itens' content to the placeholder? be cloned and replace the placeholder? replace the placeholder with the original?

The example above assumes that you will update the contents of the placeholder with the contents of the dragged elements (and that each item's properties will be identified by a class). If you need more info about the draggable (for instance, their index in the source array) one possibility is to use the `data` function.